# R build lists over links between data frame rows

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
  current_session next_session
1             811          841
2            1771         2071
3            3181         3241
4            3241         3271
5            3271         3361
6            3361         3391
```

I need to build lists for each chain of sessions that are bigger than 2 elements where a chain of such elements is defined by a link between 'next_session' to the 'current_session' of the next row. For instance, 1 chain that can be drawn from the above set is (3181,3241,3271,3361,3391).
I need to extract all lists that are at least 3 elements long, and store all these lists in 1 wrapper list.
Currently I have this code but I'm not sure it's efficient (2 loops):

```
chain <- list()
list_of_chains <- list()
for (t in 1:nrow(identical_sessions_df)){
  # init
  chain <- list(identical_sessions_df[t,1],identical_sessions_df[t,2])

 while(inidentical_sessions_df[t,2] != identical_sessions_df[t+1,1]){

   if (identical_sessions_df[t,2] == identical_sessions_df[t+1,1]){
     chain[[length(chain)+1]] <- identical_sessions_df[t+1,2]
 } 

  } else{
    list_of_chains <- c(list_of_chains,c(chain))
    chain <- NA
  }
```

I'm pretty new to R so sorry if the question is trivial and thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `data.frame` is small you can stick with loops, otherwise you can use `igraph` package and build a graph of your sessions and get the connected components of the graph, i.e. :

```
library(igraph)

# create a graph, edges are current_session --> next_session
g <- graph.data.frame(identical_sessions_df,directed=T)
# plot the graph if you want to visualize it...
#plot(g,vertex.size=25)

# decompose the graph in the connected components
sg <- decompose.graph(g,mode="weak")

# if you want to plot the sub-graphs...
#for(i in 1:length(sg)){
#  plot(sg [[i]],vertex.size=25)
#}

# create the chains list
list_of_chains <- 
lapply(sg,function(subgr){ 
  return(V(subgr)$name[topological.sort(subgr)])
})

# remove the sub-chains having <= 2 elements
list_of_chains <- list_of_chains[sapply(list_of_chains,function(x){length(x) > 2})]

# Result:
#> list_of_chains
#[[1]]
#[1] "3181" "3241" "3271" "3361" "3391"
```

Here's what you get if you plot the first graph :

[image]